# How to set 3 components in one Horizontal field without adjusting editfield width

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

```java
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
this.add(hfm);


LabelField lblheight = new LabelField("Height");

EditField lField = new EditField() {
    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        super.layout(width, height);
        this.setExtent(200, this.getHeight());
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return 200;
    }
};

Background editFieldBackground = BackgroundFactory
        .createSolidBackground(0X00F7F7FF);
XYEdges edges = new XYEdges(5, 5, 5, 5);
Border border = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(edges, 0X00D6DBDE,
        Border.STYLE_FILLED);

Bitmap switchOn = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("switch_left.png");
Bitmap switchOff = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("switch_right.png");
Bitmap switchOnFocus = Bitmap
        .getBitmapResource("switch_left_focus.png");
Bitmap switchOffFocus = Bitmap
        .getBitmapResource("switch_right_focus.png");
SwitchField sw = new SwitchField(switchOn, switchOff, switchOnFocus,
        switchOffFocus, true);
lField.setBackground(editFieldBackground);
lField.setBorder(border);
hfm.add(lblheight);
hfm.add(lField);
hfm.add(sw);
```

I used the above code for setting 3 components in one horizontal field manager, but my issue is that here I set the width for the edittext.

So, is there any other option to display 3 components in the proper manner on all devices, without adjusting the width of the edittext?

Comment: `EditField` always uses entire width of its manager, unless you stop it from doing this by overriding its with. From what I understand, you want your `Editfield` to take maximum width available after leaving the space for label and switch. You should implement your own custom `Manager` for this.

Comment: but in custom manager also i have to set width for EditField so ? what is differance between that and above code

Comment: If you use a custom manager, you need not hardcode the width. You would use the width of the screen and width of the other fields to calculate it.

Comment: ok u have any sample code for that,i am newbie in blackberry

Comment: @Kirti, do you still need help with this?